# Using ES-module with TypeScript on React

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, type-definition, esmodules

We currently export our package using NPM and trying to use ES-module to publish the package as a file. The issue is all these type-definitions will not there with the module file and that causes issues to the consumers who wanted to integrate with TypeScript. Is there a way we can do this export?

I tried to export the type definition separately in a new NPM package and for hack I added a face d.ts file for the es-module on the client side. But those seems like a hacky ways.

Comment: I caan't help you with `npm`, but FWIW you could publish to [JSR](https://jsr.io) and tell users how to import it via [the `npm` compatbility layer](https://jsr.io/docs/npm-compatibility). JSR is ***brand*** new and only just in beta, though. But it's from the Deno team, so not just a flash in the pan.